# Asynchronous call in web service

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-7, asynchronous

I'm using web service for my wp7 app and i have a difficulty in finding out whether the asynchronous call to the service returns the value or not. i have a validation depends on the response(result). The following the code snippet for calling the web service and appropriate changes that should be made to the UI.

```
private void TLP_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    objevnt.indexChanged(1, lpcountry.SelectedIndex, "depart");
    if(objevnt.CName.Count>0)
    lpcity.ItemsSource = objevnt.GetCityDetails();
}
public void indexChanged(int Travel,int index,string journey)
{
    string slCountry = null;
    switch (Travel)
    {
        case 1:
            slCountry = lstCtryDetails.lstCtrylist[index].countryId.ToString();
            //= "depart";
            travelMode = journey;
            break;
        case 2:
                slCountry = lstCtryDetails.lstCtrylist[index].countryId.ToString();
                travelMode = journey;
                break;
        case 3:
                slCountry = lstCtryDetails.lstCtrylist[index].countryId.ToString();
                travelMode = journey;
                break;
    }

    GetCities = "http://Solutions/mobileservice/Citylist/countrycode/" + slCountry;
    WebClient myClientcity = new WebClient();
    myClientcity.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(GetCities, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    myClientcity.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(myClientcity_DownloadStringCompleted);
}

private void myClientcity_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string _Countries = null;
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        _Countries = e.Result;
        parseCtry(_Countries);
    }
}

private void parseCtry(string xml)
{
    XDocument myXdoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xml));
    IEnumerable<XElement> lstElm = myXdoc.Descendants("GetCityList");
    lstCtryDetails.lstCitylist.Clear();
    foreach (XElement ele in lstElm.Elements())
    {
        if (ele.Name.ToString() != "Message")
        {
            // Fetch t Details
            if (!ele.IsEmpty && ele.Name.ToString() == "City")
            {
                lstCtryDetails.lstCitylist.Add(new cityList() { CityId = ele.Element("CityCode").Value, CityName = ele.Element("CityName").Value, CityLatitude = ele.Element("Latitude").Value, CityLongitude = ele.Element("Longitude").Value });
                CName.Add(ele.Element("CityName").Value);
                //Countchk = true;
            }
        }
    }

    lsCity = lstCtryDetails.lstCitylist;

    //chkloop = true;
}

public List<cityList> GetCityDetails()
{
    if (lsCity.Count > 0)
        return lsCity;
    return null;
}
```

Now i need to get the list of values from the getcitydetails() method. but that is reurning null due to asynchronous call. how to get the count of list, to do appropriate validations. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you currently trying to update the UI?

Comment: I wanna update the list picker according to the response of the web service.

Comment: No error but the list always returns empty... count is always 0...

Comment: is `parseCtry` being called, and is it finding any non-empty City elements?

Comment: yes the parseCtry has some values but then the condition(count>0) does n't get satisfied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the `ItemsSource` potentially before your `WebClient` has returned it's result, nor had chance to call `parseCtry`.

If you move:

```
lpcity.ItemsSource = objevnt.GetCityDetails();
```

to the end of `parseCtry` (i.e. where the comment `//chkloop = true;` is) then it will evaluate to have the correct count - but you may run into cross-thread UI access issues, but you should be able to check with something like (at the start of `DownloadStringCompleted`):

```
if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(myClientcity_DownloadStringCompleted), xml) // put us back on the UI thread if required
```

You may be better off changing the type of `lsCity` to be an `ObservableCollection<cityList>` and binding to it.

Comment: very thx rowl.. btw, if u cud explain me how to use dispatcher and observable collection in wp7. I use only list for the binding of listpickers. But I did hear that observable collection is the best usage for the binding purpose..

Comment: Rowl, the method indexchanged() is somethng that i use a few places in my app. hence i put it in a common class and waiting for the returning value to make the appropriate validation. it can be used like what u ve prescribed but then i ve to use it all those pages.. for reusability only i need it to make it precise..

Comment: Rather than cram in a discussion on the benefits of using ObservableCollection<T> (and its friends), I'd suggest instead reading [MSDN's article on implementing MVVM on Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg521153(v=vs.92).aspx) which walks you through the *how*.

Comment: how bout the 2nd qust that i ve asked. Rowl, the method indexchanged() is somethng that i use a few places in my app. hence i put it in a common class and waiting for the returning value to make the appropriate validation. it can be used like what u ve prescribed but then i ve to use it all those pages.. for reusability only i need it to make it precise..

Comment: Following the MVVM model does kind of answer that as well -- your pages (views) can use view-models that can share models - you *could* move that logic into a different  layer and share it amongst the view-models and the views that are bound against them.

Comment: thanx for ur quik response rowl. i ll go thru that. mean while i have some more doubts in wp7. I have used bing map where i locate the current location using gps and i'm getting the co-ordinates using geoco-ordinatewatcher as well and pin the current location with pushpin. but my issue is that i wanna get the current city and country name where the pushpin is pointing. i couldn't get that using map.center property. can u help me out for this issue...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the callback before performing the webrequest?

```
myClientcity.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(myClientcity_DownloadStringCompleted);
myClientcity.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(GetCities, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

=== Updated ===

From your comments I think I understand that problem. What you want is to [data bind](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=webhp&q=databinding%20windows%20phone%207&oq=data%20binding%20windows%20&aq=2s&aqi=g-s3g-K1&aql=&gs_l=serp.3.2.0i10l3j0i30.1228.2456.0.3575.10.9.0.0.0.0.126.652.7j2.9.0...0.0._6rnRxTuc2Y&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=56d372ad768dfec4&ion=1&biw=1383&bih=828) an `ObservableCollection<T>` to your UI element `lpCity`. If for instance if `lpCity` was data bound to `lsCity` (implementing `ObservableCollection<T>`), once `lpCity` is updated via a asynchronous web request, the UI element will update automatically.

I would write out a code skeleton for you, I'm away from my Windows PC.

Comment: I ve tried async after the event handler but then response of the web service is asnchronous therefore for the below condition  if(objevnt.CName.Count>0)
    lpcity.ItemsSource = objevnt.GetCityDetails();else  MessageBox.Show("No Cities Available"); always redirects to the else part eventhough i get the list of cities from the web service